# U-Link 802.IIN Wireless Issue on Freya

Tags: release-freya, networking

I have just installed the latest version, 0.3.1 Freya 32 bit, but cannot get my usb wireless adaptor to work. It is a U-Link 802.llN adaptor and the supplied drivers are RTL8192EU.

Any ideas?

==========================================================================
Output as requested:

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 19
   bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 02
   serial: 00:23:7d:2f:6b:73
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k duplex=full firmware=0.4-3 ip=192.168.178.31 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:30 memory:f0500000-f051ffff memory:f0525000-f0525fff ioport:1100(size=32)
```

==========================================================================

Here is the install file for the driver:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Auto install for 8192cu
# September, 1 2010 v1.0.0, willisTang
# 
# Add make_drv to select chip type
# Novembor, 21 2011 v1.1.0, Jeff Hung
################################################################################

echo "##################################################"
echo "Realtek Wi-Fi driver Auto installation script"
echo "Novembor, 21 2011 v1.1.0"
echo "##################################################"

################################################################################
#   Decompress the driver source tal ball
################################################################################
cd driver
Drvfoulder=`ls |grep .tar.gz`
echo "Decompress the driver source tar ball:"
echo "  "$Drvfoulder
tar zxvf $Drvfoulder

Drvfoulder=`ls |grep -iv '.tar.gz'`
echo "$Drvfoulder"
cd  $Drvfoulder

################################################################################
#   If makd_drv exixt, execute it to select chip type
################################################################################
if [ -e ./make_drv ]; then
./make_drv
fi

################################################################################
#                       make clean
################################################################################
echo "Authentication requested [root] for make clean:"
if [ "`uname -r |grep fc`" == " " ]; then
        sudo su -c "make clean"; Error=$?
else
        su -c "make clean"; Error=$?
fi

################################################################################
#   Compile the driver
################################################################################
echo "Authentication requested [root] for make driver:"
if [ "`uname -r |grep fc`" == " " ]; then
sudo su -c make; Error=$?
else    
su -c make; Error=$?
fi
################################################################################
#   Check whether or not the driver compilation is done
################################################################################
module=`ls |grep -i 'ko'`
echo "##################################################"
if [ "$Error" != 0 ];then
echo "Compile make driver error: $Error"
echo "Please check error Mesg"
echo "##################################################"
exit
else
echo "Compile make driver ok!!" 
echo "##################################################"
fi

if [ "`uname -r |grep fc`" == " " ]; then
echo "Authentication requested [root] for remove driver:"
sudo su -c "rmmod $module"
echo "Authentication requested [root] for insert driver:"
sudo su -c "insmod $module"
echo "Authentication requested [root] for install driver:"
sudo su -c "make install"
else
echo "Authentication requested [root] for remove driver:"
su -c "rmmod $module"
echo "Authentication requested [root] for insert driver:"
su -c "insmod $module"
echo "Authentication requested [root] for install driver:"
su -c "make install"
fi
echo "##################################################"
echo "The Setup Script is completed !"
echo "##################################################"

=========================================================================
```

Comment: I have the output in a file, how do I add that to the post?

Comment: please [edit] post and add output of `sudo lshw -C network`

Comment: Do you think an upgrade to the latest version will fix this?

Comment: no need to add SOLVED to title. You can accept after 48 hrs :)

Answer (score 1):

So, after hours of googling I ended up here: https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/reserve-7#TOC-Realtek-RTL8188EU-chipset-0bda:8179-
There was a section 6 which provided a link to an updated? driver and some instructions that worked perfectly.  I now have wireless Yay.  :-)